# How do I interpolate values of missing columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables i.e., `tbl1` and `tbl2` in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database. tbl1 contains data (timestamp without time zone) like:

```
Start_time              
1996-06-07 00:00:00     
1997-02-03 00:00:00     
2000-07-09 00:00:00
```

and `tbl2` contains some values like this:

```
ID.    veh_1995    veh_2000    
1      200         425         
2      400         478         
3      150         300         
4      700         800         
5      900         1500
```

The following query interpolates the values of missing years (gap between years columns) for `tbl2:

```
 SELECT 
        veh_1995,
       (veh_1995 + (veh_2000 - veh_1995) * 0.2)::int AS veh_1996,
       (veh_1995 + (veh_2000 - veh_1995) * 0.4)::int AS veh_1997,
       (veh_1995 + (veh_2000 - veh_1995) * 0.6)::int AS veh_1998,
       (veh_1995 + (veh_2000 - veh_1995) * 0.8)::int AS veh_1999,
       veh_2000
 from tbl2
```

I need to modify above query such that:

- for each `start time` row in `tbl1`, the query should check whether there are some missing years columns in `tbl2`
- if yes then interpolate those missing columns values and return all columns with reference to years in `start_time`

Expected output:

```
Year          value
1996          ...
1997          ...
2000          ...
```

I would be thankful if someone could help me to modify above query to get my desired output?

Comment: Is your depiction of the expected output complete?  Your phrase "return all columns with reference to years in start_time" suggests that you would want start_time in the output as well.  Also consider that an output format with individual columns for the year and the value may be a better representation of the data (and easier to produce)--the same goes for your tbl2.

Comment: You, probably are right. In principle, I want to select values for each year in start_time. If there are some missing years then query interpolates and return values for all years in start_time. Thus, it can be in output. Just going to edit the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Is this more or less what you're looking for?

```
with yrs as (
    select
        t2.*,
        start_time,
        generate_series(cast(extract(year from start_time) as integer), 2000) as interp_yr
    from
        tbl2 as t2,
        tbl1 as t1
    where
        extract(year from start_time) between 1995 and 2000
    )
select
    iy.*,
    veh_1995 + (veh_2000 - veh_1995) * (interp_yr - 1995)/5 as interp_val
from
    yrs as iy;
```